# Permission to make and manage phone calls

Tags: permissions

I just bought a second hand phone (my first device running android). I'm surprised by the fact that three times I've been asked for permission to make and manage phone calls. This is a very scary thing to allow and it's even for things that don't seem to need it. I first noticed it when I wanted to run Diagnostics. It asks to Allow Support to make and manage phone calls. This is already strange but perhaps could be justified in the process of running diagnostics. But I tried some other things to check the permissions that they would ask and also the pre-installed Xperia File Transfer Mobile and even the FM radio ask for it. All of these are pre-installed and system apps.

Is this normal? Would you give these permissions? Or is there something wrong with the phone (malware?)?

(For now there is no sim in the phone so the damage that it can do is very limited.)

---

I already did a factory reset and the issue persists.

Comment: I recommend doing a system reset. This should get rid of all third-party apps and give a clean system to start with. System apps shouldn't need to ask for any basic permission like this.

Comment: @GiantTree, I will do this although I think the factory data reset was done just before handing it to me (I can do it again to make sure, trust but verify), but do you mean this or is there a cleaner way to reset the whole device? And by the way I'm Arliden but I was an idiot and used a guest account for stupid reasons without considering the inconvenience of using one.

Comment: @Kvothe I mean just doing a factory reset through the settings, that should be enough. If you suspect any changes to the system, you have to install a fresh stock ROM, but the steps involved in doing that vary by device and manufacturer.

Comment: @GaintTree, thanks. I just did the factory reset and these apps still ask for the same permission. Do you think there is something shady about this?

Answer (score 1):

Does seem very scary given permission to almost all apps requirements to agree to many requests such as to all questions an apps wants from a person .Fear not it's normal in companies software automatically .The requirement consist of few or many wanting phone ,SMS,contacts ect: Give consent some apps won't let install otherwise why !!we don't know Go to settings click on apps go through as many as wishes turn off what you don't want a company app having to many of your personal details that's it (Done ) no need to reset your devices it's inconvenient and will need to back up your files ,folders ,contacts in the meanwhile in doing so may loose  precious photo's and possibly some files .Just go to settings everytime you experience issues once you know how it's easy and less time consuming and save your sanity .

Answer (score 0):

You can trust on system apps(pre installed) by allowing them these changes. I don't explain much.

But in case you are feeling malicious activities you can deny them in settings freely as per you use. You can allow them once to use and deny after use. That simple.

Note: Just make sure your device doesn't giving notification/location/media permission to any third party app which doesn't have to do anything with these permissions.

Comment: I don't agree with this suggestion of trusting system apps blindly. Most users with budget constraints are forced to choose devices from many vendors who employs 
 questionable strategies to  get revenue (by collecting user data through system apps and what not). Furthermore, I don't agree with giving them access once and revoking it later. If you give Phone permission for once, they can record the IMEI number at that time and send it with other details instantaneously to who knows where.

Answer (score 0):

In samsung FAQ its it asks this because " This is an Android Marshmallow permission which enables access to the default phone app in your device, and helps you to make phone calls to Samsung Customer Service directly from the Help Centre in mySamsung app."

If this is the answer, the message should not say "... allow.. make and manage phone calls"  oh brother... an example of what would call super-geek-speak .   That is confusing of actual function.  I, too have not allowed this feature yet .although I really REALLY want to make use of a simple feature: SAMSUNG NOTES.